# Can anyone recommend an explorer using the client object model?

Tags: client-object-model, explorer

I'm looking for an explorer for a sharepoint site that's using the client object model undercover.

It would be great if this explorer would show all the information/properties one could get from this model.

Is there anything like this that exists?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, found something.

[SharePoint 2010 explorer (using the Client object model)](http://stefan-stanev-sharepoint-blog.blogspot.ca/2010/05/sharepoint-2010-explorer-using-client.html)

It is really great and the source code is provided !!!

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for SharePoint Manager, which shows you everything in your farm,

http://spm.codeplex.com/

**Edit**

If above doesn't work then you can try answers in this link given below,

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11628349/get-the-all-infromation-of-sharepoint-server-using-client-object-model

Comment: Thanks for the link but I want to use the client object model, hence the client-object-model tag ;)

Comment: I updated my answer :)

Comment: Unfortunately, the stackoverflow answer you linked does help.

Comment: @Stécy does help ? or you mean it didn't help, that question got all the code, you just need to develop a windows form app, I am not aware of any free application already there which does what you want already.

Comment: Oh, I meant does NOT help...

Comment: I am looking for an already made application since I don't have the time right now to do it and if something exists then why reinvent the wheel?